# Cannot access mounted shared NAS directory with ownCloud

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I managed to run `ownCloud` on my RaspberryPi 2 on Raspbian. Now I am trying to move the data directory to my NAS.

I already shared a folder on my NAS with `CIFS` and mounted the folder.
This allows me to access the shared directory via the command line and manipulate entries. *So that works.* However, when opening ownCloud in my browser, I get the following error message:

> Data directory (/home/pi/Cloud/storage) is readable by other users
>
> Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.

So I tried to adjust the permissions in the `/etc/fstab` file, where I mounted the shared directory. This also worked out, but changes the owner from `www-data` to `pi`. With the result that ownCloud does not run at all, since the data directory has to be owned by `www-data`.

I mounted the shared folder by adding the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//<NAS-IP>/<sharedFolder> /home/pi/Cloud/storage cifs username=<my username>,password=<my password>,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,dir_mode=770,file_mode=770,umask=0007 0 0
```

Which results in these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi    pi    4096 Sep  2  23:15 storage
```

So the problem is that the data directory can be read by all users, but when I restrict the permissions, it is not owned by `www-data` anymore.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? It seems that I am so close to have ownCloud running, but I can't figure out this last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your NAS supports unix extensions that are overriding your mount settings. The man page for [mount.cifs](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) notes that `dir_mode`, `file_mode`, `uid` and `gid` can be overridden by the server if it supports unix extensions (very likely if it is a Linux based NAS).

If this is the case you might be able to change the permissions on the folder directly. If that doesn't work try mounting with the `nounix` option to disable the extensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right, I had to change the permissions on the NAS directly. At first I created the folder as `admin` in the GUI of the NAS. But then I created it via SSH as the same user that I specified in my `/etc/fstab/` file and now it works. I'm getting a different error now, but that is not related to permissions anymore :)